# Session of logged user return undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have custom login function in Laravel 5.4 which seems to work but not exactly. What I have in UserController.php is

```
public function loginSubmit() 
{
    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    if (!Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password)) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $user->last_login = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
    Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
    //dd(Session::get('user', null));   

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

`dd(Session::get('user', null));` return

```
array:1 [▼
  "user_id" => 1
]
```

Which means that user with ID=1 is logged and is in stored in session. In `BaseController.php` which sharing the user session I have this

```
public static function isLoggedIn() 
{
    $user = Session::get('user', null);
    if ($user !== null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when I tried to show the username of the logged in user

```
{{ $user->username }}
```

I've got error

> Undefined variable: user

This my Users model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent; 
use DB;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract 
{

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with my session here?

Comment: Is there a need to assign user to session like this? You can access logged in user with `Auth::user()`, or check if they're logged in `Auth::check()`.

Comment: `{{ Auth::user()->username }}` is returning `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Replace `Session::put()` with `Auth::login($user)`

Comment: So actually in this case I don't need `isLoggedIn()` function?

Comment: it can return `Auth::check()`, which is probably a bit pointless. If my comments helped you I will make it an answer

Comment: It only works if he is using the standard laravel Auth, while Peter is using a custom method.

Comment: Looks like I didn't removed standard laravel Auth because it's working. And yes, I've tried to use my custom function.

Comment: Well if you are using Auth there is no need of a custom module, look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: if you're using your own login function I think the function name should be `login` so that it overwrites the scaffolded one.. but I could be wrong or that might be unnecessary there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `$user` is not defined in the blade file you are using.

Call the view with the user as a parameter (i think this is the best approach):

```
$user = Session::get('user', null);
return view('yourview')->with(['user' => $user];
```

Or use the Session in your blade file:

```
{{ Session::get('user', null)->username }}
```

EDIT: to use `View::share`. You can put this inside the `boot` function of your Service provider:

```
    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            $user = Session::get('user', null);
            View::share('user', $user);
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Do you prefer `with` to `compact` because I guess you can use different names in the blade then? Or can you do that with `compact` as well?

Comment: You can do with `compact` as well. I just don't like the idea of using the session in your blade file, because there is no need to access the Session everytime if you store the User object in a variable

Comment: But I have this in `setupLayout()` function `View::share('user', $user);` which should share the user, no? I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: Thanks very much!